# How do you save values from an autosuggest textbox on a web page?

Tags: html, autosuggest

I want to be able to save the values that I get from an autosuggest text box on a web page. E.g there is a website with an autosuggest text box and when I type "A", it throws me everything it has on that starting with A in the suggestor. I want to be able to save those values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking about the browser's behaviour, you can't. It's a client feature that should not be accessible by the server (e.g. through Javascript) for security reasons.